# I am not able to move or navigate to a file in vscode terminal powershell

Tags: node.js, linux, visual-studio, cmd, terminal

I have made a folder name *notes* and my terminal is present in  *notes* folder currently and I am trying to move further in a file called *web.js* ,so I used command *cd web/* which isn't seem to work and is always throwing error I also tried *cd ./web/ , cd .\web* ,nothing is working don't know why ? can anyone help me out? I need to open npm in my *web.js* file but not able to do so...
Kindly Help:)!
This is the error :

````
Devlopment\Notes\web\' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd web/
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:  
   \Web Devlopment\Notes\web\:String) [Set-Locat   
  ion], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Micros  
   oft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand```
````

Comment: what error ? can you do "pwd", then "ls" then "cd web" and paste the results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to rund web.js you can use

```
node web.js
```

cd works only with folders. You can cd into notes but web.js is a file that you can run via scripts.

Comment: thanks sir for answer ..helped me alot:) Stay Happy....

Comment: No Problem. Feel free to mark my comment as answer.